# MVC 5 Edit with ViewModel by reusing EF Generated Code

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Business **Model** and an **EditBusinessViewModel**.

In MVC 4 I would use code something like this to edit a record:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MainMenu mainmenu)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.MainMenus.Attach(mainmenu);
        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(mainmenu, EntityState.Modified);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(mainmenu);
}
```

Now the auto generated code in MVC 5 looks like this, I've modified this Action to only include fields from my EditBusinessViewModel and named it **Edit2**:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Edit2([Bind(Include = "ID,BusinessName,BusinessDescription,BusinessAddress,BusinessPhoneOne,BusinessPhoneTwo,BusinessWeb,BusinessEmail,BusinessMelRef")] EditBusinessViewModel business)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(business).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Redirect("~/Home/Index/" + business.ID);
    }
    return View(business);
}
```

I have the **Get** part working, my **Model** and **View** are working by returning:

```
return View(new EditBusinessViewModel(business));
```

But when I post back, I get an error on this line:

```
db.Entry(business).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

**The entity type EditBusinessViewModel is not part of the model for the current context.** Which it is not and the reason for the ViewModel, I guess?

What I would like to know is can I use this code or is there something else I should be doing?

**Update**

I've been thinking about this too deeply and a ViewModel is just that, a **ViewModel** so  now I have:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Edit2([Bind(Include = "ID,BusinessDescription,BusinessAddress,BusinessPhoneOne,BusinessPhoneTwo,BusinessWeb,BusinessEmail,BusinessMelRef")] EditBusinessViewModel business)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        business.UserEmail = User.Identity.GetUserName();

        Business newbus = db.Businesses.Find(business.ID);
        {
            newbus.BusinessDescription = business.BusinessDescription;
            newbus.BusinessAddress = business.BusinessAddress;
        };

        db.Entry(newbus).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Redirect("~/Home/Index/" + business.ID);
    }
    return View(business);
}
```

This way I post back the data I need from the view in the View Model, find the entity in the database by its matching ID and update it with the EF scaffold code.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I think your updated way is a very reasonable way to go about it.  View Models provide a nice abstraction, you pay a little overhead when you have to look a model from your DB context, but in the grand scheme I've found it's worth it for many use cases, to insulate your models from the front end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you won't be able to use your current code, for reasons I believe you're pointing to in your question itself.  You're working with two different types, one that is mapped from a DB table and one that you are using specifically for your Views and is not mapped.  Your Entity Model, you don't say which version of EF, but with MVC 5 I assume it's 6 or 6.1.

So you have your entity POCO generated by EF text template, and you have you ViewModel.  Even if the properties were identical, EF would not take your ViewModel type, because it has no mapping definition in the edmx, this is the reason it says it's not in the current context as you've already recognized.

There are some decent ways to work in this system though.  IF you desire to use separate entities and ViewModels, which I personally do in most of my own code. You could :

1. It seems like you have an ID, if that ID points to a unique ID on the EF Model, you could do a look up for an entity with that ID and then update the values of the entity with the values from your ViewModel and then save the entity with StateModified instead of the ViewModel.
2. If the properties are exactly the same or very similar, between your Model and ViewModel, you could look at something like AutoMapper, https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper, which would enable you to map your ViewModel directly to an instance of your entity Model Type.
3. If you're Model and ViewModel are vastly different, you could build a static tranform, not sure how many people do this but I like them.  Essentially you define two static methods that enable you to convert your Model to your ViewModel and vice versa.  The benefit is anywhere you need to do this you can call one method, and if the structure of either type changes you just have to update this in one location.
4. You say *autogenerated code in MVC 5*, You could mean just the default example code that comes with EF 5 but I think you're talking about MVC 5 Scaffolding.  http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/aspnet-scaffolding-overview; if so, the code for these should not need much alteration at least not in the Controller side, unless you have specialty domain logic which it doesn't appear like you do.  If you wanted to use separate ViewModels I suppose you could, in conjunction with one of the recommendations above, but the point of Scaffolding is to remove much of the plumbing that you have to do when exposing DB Models for basic CRUD methods.

If I've missed the mark on what you're looking for please reply in a comment.  Also, it's a bit hard to provide code examples for the above recommendations without seeing the class definitions for your two models.  I think the descriptions should be enough to go off of, if you think one will fit your use case well?  But, if you'd like some simple code examples update your answer with the code for those classes and I can provide some.

Answer (score 2):

From your posted snippet:

```
return View(new EditBusinessViewModel(business));
```

Here, `business` is **not your ViewModel**, but a variable (presumably your entity from the db) that is used in *your ViewModel's constructor*. I can only assume it's passed with the intent of storing it in one of your ViewModel's properties.

```
public ActionResult Edit2([Bind(Include = "...")] EditBusinessViewModel business)
```

Here, `business` *is* your ViewModel. It has the type `EditBusinessViewModel`, as you can see. But in that method you make the following call:

```
db.Entry(business).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

`EditBusinessViewModel` is not a type known by EF, since it is your viewmodel. You are supposed to pass your *entity* to the database. The ViewModel should only be used in your MVC project.

I'm pretty sure that one of the properties of your `EditBusinessViewModel` is the entity you need. This is vaguely confirmed by the fact that you pass your entity in the `EditBusinessViewModel` constructor.

I don't know what the property is called, since you didn't post the ViewModel's class. Assuming it's called `MyEntity`, this should do the trick:

```
db.Entry(business.MyEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

But for clarity, I'd suggest renaming that parameter to prevent any confusion between separate uses of a `business` variable. Change it to `businessVM` or something similar so you're always reminded that you're working with a **ViewModel**, not an **entity**.